# PHP Gmail API Invalid Grant: Code was already redeemed (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail, gmail-api

First of all I want to say that I read all the other post about this same problem and I couldn't find a solution.

This is the error:

> exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed.

In localhost, it works perfect. I can debug it and I get Google plus && emails info without problem.

I create a new credential for production (Web App) and I set my oauth return uri in: Authorized redirect URI
(http://www.__myweb_.com/plus_gmail/oauth2callback)

It works, because I can accept and I get the code in callback, but it fails when I try to authenticate;

I also tried to revokeToken and my Session is empty...

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks a lot!!

This is my code:

```
function __construct()
{
    define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret_online.json');
    $this->redirect_url=base_url()."plus_gmail/oauth2callback";
    $this->client = new Google_Client();
    $this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
    $this->client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH); 
    $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_LOGIN);
    $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::PLUS_ME);
    $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_EMAIL);
    $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Plus::USERINFO_PROFILE);
    $this->client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($this->redirect_url);
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
    $this->client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
}

function index()
{
    $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

function oauth2callback()
{
    if (! isset($_GET['code'])) 
    {
        echo "Error getting code"
    } 
    else
    {
        $token=$_GET['code'];
        $data["token"]=$token;

        try
        {
            $this->client->authenticate($token);
            $access_token = $this->client->getAccessToken();

            $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
            $me=$plus->people->get('me');

            $this->daouser->newUserPlus($me,$access_token);
            var_dump($me);
            $this->readEmailsId($this->client);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            var_dump($e)
        }             
    }
}
```

I also need to know why it shows me the var_dump($e), but I have a new row in my database withe user google plus info.

I delete access to my app in my gmail account (https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) and give access again getting the same error (Code was already redeemed). I used a new gmail account and I get also the same error...

Comment: "Code was already redeemed." error is thrown when you are trying to use an authorization code that has already been used. The given authorization code can be used only once.

Comment: But why I have in my database all the access_token, including refresh_token? It means that it works! But it shows the exception. I'm thinking that maybe is calling twice to my callback and I don't know why...

Comment: It means that you are using the authentication code not the refreshtoken to get a new access token.   The authentication code is only used once to get the refresh token.  Then it will no longer work.

Comment: No, I test it with new users and I have a new row in my database with his info but it prints the exception. I don't why but it seems its calling twice. The first time it woks good, but the second time it is using the same code, so It shows that the code was already redeem...

Comment: exactly so fix your code so you stop redeeming it twice and you are all set.   something with this maybe  $token=$_GET['code'];?

Comment: The only solution is to save code in my database and check if it was used? The code is unique for every gmail account?

Comment: remember the code is useless to you.  You need the refresh token.  Yes the refresh token will be unique to each user who authenticates your app.

Comment: I know that, but It is a new user. It means that I have not refresh token and if google redirect twice to my function, the only way to know the second call is saving that code. What I really want is not calling twice...